# Trying to pivot event dates in t-sql without using a cursor

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

[image]

What I want is to get to this:

[image]

`EventTypeId` 1 and 3 are valid start events and `EventTypeId` of 2 is the only valid end event.

I have tried to do a pivot, but I don't believe a pivot will get me the multiple events for a person in the result set.

```
SELECT PersonId, [1],[3],[2] 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT PersonId, EventTypeId, EventDate 
    from #PersonEvent
    ) as SourceTable 
PIVOT 
    (
    count(EventDate) FOR EventTypeId 
    IN ([1],[3],[2]) 
    ) as PivotTable 

Select PersonID, 
    Min(Case WHEN EventTypeId IN (1,3) THEN EventDate END) as StartDate, 
    Min(Case WHEN EventTypeId IN (2) THEN EventDate END) as EndDate 
FROM #PersonEvent 
group by personid
```

I can do a cursor, but my original table is over 90,000 rows, and this is to be for a report, so I don't think I can use that option.  Any other thoughts that I might be missing?

Comment: And I forgot to mention that EvenTypeId 1 and 3 are valid start events, and EventTypeId of 2 is the only valid end event

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include what you have tried?

Comment: I cant add another image with the two options I have tried, but they are like this:

Comment: SELECT PersonId, [1],[3],[2]
FROM (SELECT PersonId, EventTypeId, EventDate from PersonEvent) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
 (EventDate)
 FOR EventTypeId IN ([1],[3],[2])
)as PivotTable

Select PersonID,
 Min(Case WHEN EventTypeId IN (1,3) THEN EventDate END) as StartDate,
 Min(Case WHEN EventTypeId IN (2) THEN EventDate END) as EndDate
 FROM PersonEvent
 group by personid

Comment: What version of Sql Server?

Comment: SQL Server version 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the table is called `[dbo].[PersonEventRecords]` this will work...

```
With    StartEvents As
(
        Select  *
        From    [dbo].[PersonEventRecords]
            Where   EventTypeId In (1,3)
),      EndEvents As
(
        Select  *
        From    [dbo].[PersonEventRecords]
        Where   EventTypeId In (2)
)
Select  IsNull(se.PersonId,ee.PersonId) As PersonId, 
        se.EventTypeId As StartEventTypeId,
        se.EventDate As StartEventDate, 
        ee.EventTypeId As EndEventTypeId,
        ee.EventDate As EndEventDate
From    StartEvents se
Full    Outer Join  EndEvents ee
        On  se.PersonId = ee.PersonId
        And se.EventSequence = ee.EventSequence - 1
Order   By IsNull(se.PersonId,ee.PersonId),
        IsNull(se.EventDate,ee.EventDate);


/**** TEST DATA ****/
If      Object_ID('[dbo].[PersonEventRecords]') Is Not Null 
            Drop Table [dbo].[PersonEventRecords];

Create  Table [dbo].[PersonEventRecords] 
    (
        PersonId Int,
        EventTypeId Int,
        EventDate Date,
        EventSequence Int
    );

Insert  [dbo].[PersonEventRecords]
Select  1,1,'2012-10-13',1
Union All
Select  1,2,'2012-10-20',2
Union All
Select  1,1,'2012-11-01',3
Union All
Select  1,2,'2012-11-13',4
Union All
Select  2,1,'2012-05-07',1
Union All
Select  2,2,'2012-06-01',2
Union All
Select  2,3,'2012-07-01',3
Union All
Select  2,2,'2012-08-30',4
Union All
Select  3,2,'2012-04-05',1
Union All
Select  3,1,'2012-05-04',2
Union All
Select  3,2,'2012-05-24',3
Union All
Select  4,1,'2013-01-03',1
Union All
Select  4,1,'2013-02-20',2
Union All
Select  4,2,'2013-03-20',3;
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Shouldn't 4-1 end on 2013-03-20?

Comment: No.  Part of my issues are data anomalies.  The real output is to calculate days between events.  With the nulls, I can display them as unmatched events, and the data can be fixed.

Comment: Well, if I run this query, besides null for 4-1 I also get 4 / 1 / 2012-02-20 / 2 / 2013-02-20, which is weird as 2013-02-20 was a date of a start event (1)

Comment: I added the test data I used to test it.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I've made a mistake while transferring data from the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT E1.PersonId, E1.EventTypeId, E1.EventDate, E2.EventTypeId, E2.EventDate
FROM PersonEvent AS E1
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 PersonEvent.EventTypeId, PersonEvent.EventDate
    FROM PersonEvent
    WHERE PersonEvent.PersonId = E1.PersonId
        AND PersonEvent.EventSequence = E1.EventSequence + 1
        AND PersonEvent.EventTypeId = 2
) AS E2
WHERE E1.EventTypeId = 1 OR E1.EventTypeId = 3

UNION

SELECT E3.PersonId, NULL, NULL, E3.EventTypeId, E3.EventDate
FROM PersonEvent E3
WHERE E3.EventTypeId = 2
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM PersonEvent
    WHERE PersonEvent.PersonId = E3.PersonId
    AND PersonEvent.EventSequence = E3.EventSequence - 1)
```

It is not completely clear how do you want the result to be ordered – add order as needed.